# How to use mvc-mini-profiler with mysql connection?

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm currently trying to use the [mvc-mini-profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) with a MySQL Connection. Is there a way to do this with some kind of custom wrapper?

```
var mysqlConn = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; ...");
string commandText = "SELECT ...";

ProfiledDbConnection profiledConn = new ProfiledDbConnection(mysqlConn, MiniProfiler.Current);           

var sqlCom = new MySqlCommand(commandText, profiledConn); // error, expects MySQLConnection, not DBConnection
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
var sqlCom = profiledConn.CreateCommand(); 
sqlCom.CommandText = commandText;
```

It is critical the commands are intercepted for the profiling to work.

Comment: Thanks, but I have used the MySqlCommand a lot before and now I can't see a way to get from a normal SqlCommand to the MySql one. 
But nevermind, I will switch to Dapper so I can use the profiled connection without problems.